# Display a different image on combo box change in Access without file paths

Tags: image, ms-access, combobox

I am creating a form that contains a combo box, lets say it's called 'Postcode_cb'. I want to have a unique image displayed for each of the items in that combo box. The images have to be in the same position and replace each other when the combo box is changed so that there is only ever 1 image. This has to be done without the use of file paths.

For example:

[image: Combo box item 1 displays image 1]

[image: Combo box item 2 displays image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: create table [tblImg]([id], [picture]) where [id] is long and [picture] is OLE. 
Insert two records with id=1 and id=2, embed corresponding images into [picture] field.

Then create stanalone form [frmImages] with rowsource [tblImg] and put 'bound object frame' with control source [picture].

Put [frmImages] as sub form at your main form.

Set LinkMasterFields to [Postcode_cb] and LinkChildFields to [id].

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this on a database that gives out star rating of hotels. As you browse through the hotels it displays actual stars depending on the rating. The way that i did this was placed all the images in 1 spot (Placing them on top of one another) Give each image a name. and set them all to visible = no.

Example Img1, Img2 etc. until all images have a name.

Then open Visual basic and create a sub called Private Sub Form_Current() if you don't already have one. Then under this sub use the following Code

```
Forms![FormName]![ComboBoxName].SetFocus
Select Case Forms![FormName]![ComboBoxName].Text
    Case Is = ""
Forms![FormName]!img1.Visible = False
Forms![FormName]!img2.Visible = False
    Case Is = "1"
Forms![FormName]!img1.Visible = True
    Case Is = "2"
Forms![FormName]!img2.Visible = True
End Select
```

This is only good if you only have something like 5 to 10 images anything more would be a lot harder to deal with in this way.

There maybe other ways people can suggest i found this the most easiest for my needs.